# how i split a array in c#

Tags: c#, arrays, string

I am new to the C # language and would like to know how I do to cut or manipulate data from an array that is grouped in a single line

the data is like this

[image]
.

the command line to make the data appear

`IList<IList<Object>> values = response.Values;`

```
            if (values != null && values.Count > 0)
            {
                foreach (var row in values)
                {        
                    Console.WriteLine(row[0]);
             String str = row[0].ToString().Split(Environment.NewLine,row[0]);
                }
              }
```

even converting the object to string I'm having an error in this conversion

**EDIT**

I managed to get him to remove whatever I want using the split I think this is already a start

```
                    try
                    {
                    String[] str = row[0].ToString().Split(null);
                    Console.WriteLine(str[0]);
                    Console.WriteLine($"{row[0]}");
                    catch (Exception)
                    {

                    }
```

i used a `try` to prevent errors

Comment: Can you add more code. Like how is `row` defined, and how is `row[0]` filled?

Comment: `IList<Object>` is rarely useful. Show us what `response.Values` contains from your debugger, not from a screenshot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned above, you can use `Split` method to split the string. For example, if string value is `"Europe, Asia, Africa"`:

```
string stringToSplit = "Europe, Asia, Africa";
string[] arrayOfString = stringToSplit.Split(',');
```

This overload (version) of `Split` method takes one argument and that is the character used to split the string. Result will be `Europe`, `Asia` and `Africa`. However, `Asia` and `Africa` will have one space character (`' '`) in the beginning because there is a space before those words in `stringToSplit`. So additionally, you need to trim elements of `arrayOfString` by adding

```
.Select(s => s.Trim()).ToArray()
```

The result would look like this:

```
string stringToSplit = "Europe, Asia, Africa";
string[] arrayOfString = stringToSplit.Split(',').Select(s => s.Trim()).ToArray();
```

`stringToSplit` is string you want to split using `','` character. `Split(',')` is the method that splits the string using `','` character and the result of that method is an array of `string`-s. `Select(s => s.Trim())` takes each element of that array and trims it (removes all empty spaces from the beginning and from the end) and the result of it is a **list** of strings. `s` is just an alias for element, you can name it whatever you want. `ToArray` is a method that converts, in this case the list returned by `Select(s => s.Trim())`, to an array. Finally, the result stored in `arrayOfString` is an array containing trimmed strings.

Having in mind the result you've posted, in your example

```
IList<IList<Object>> values = response.Values;

if (values != null && values.Count > 0)
{
    foreach (var row in values)
    {        
        Console.WriteLine(row[0]);
    }
}
```

`values` is a list of lists. In other words, each element of `values` (named `row` in the example) is a list. After you check if `values` exists (`values != null`) and if has elements (`values.Count > 0`), you go through each element (`row`) of `values`. Those elements are lists (`IList<Object>`) and you write the first element of each `row` by using `row[0]`.

Definition `IList<IList<Object>> values` says that `row` is of type `IList<Object>`, which means that every element of `row` is of type `Object`. Method `WriteLine` has an overload (version) that accepts an argument of type `Object` as it is in this case. That argument is then implicitly (in the background) converted to type `string`.

Looking at the output, there's no doubt that those element of type `Object` are actually strings, otherwise it will write name of the type, or some other data not useful, or not readable.

There are two possibilities.

Either list `values` contains one element (one list of objects, `row`) and the first element of `row` is a string (it is definitely of type `string`) that contains all those names separated by `Environment.NewLine`, or list `values` contains multiple elements (lists of objects, `row`-s) and the first element of each `row` is a string that contains single name.

If you know that you accept one string and need to separate it, than ok, and it would be the first possibility. In that case you could try

```
row[0].ToString().Split('\n')
```

However, it seems like the other case, where there are multiple lists of objects and the first one is name. In that case you don't need to split anything.

Comment: i tried many things and get output this `System.String[]` for all lines

Comment: You have probably passed entire array to `WriteLine` instead of its elements and as output you have got name of the array type. Inside existing `foreach`, instead of `WriteLine` and other code inside that `foreach`, create a variable `string[] stringArray` and store the split to that variable. Then create another one `foreach` and write every element of array: `foreach (var str in stringArray) { Console.WriteLine(str); }`.

Answer (score 2):

First, convert the object to a string with `.ToString()` and then use the `.Split()` function together with `Environment.NewLine` as the token for the splitting.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like one string, but with newlines inside.

If this is the case then you can split using newline character as separator.

For instance : `var individualLines = row[0].Split(new[] { Environment.NewLine });`

Comment: I'm having an error
`String str = row[0].ToString().Split(Environment.NewLine,row[0]);` i can convert string to char and obj to char

Comment: @FelipeCruz I changed the syntax a bit, but now I realized something : the returned result of `string.Split()` is an array, not a single `string`. So you should use `var strs = ...`, or `string[] strs = ....`, not `string str = ....`.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you can unwind a list of lists such as `IList<List<object>>` with the `.SelectMany()` command from `System.Linq`.

Example program below:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            IList<IList<object>> values = new List<IList<object>>
            {
                new object[] { "Kassadin" },
                new object[] { "Wukong" },
                new object[] { "Lucian-" },
                new object[] { "Akali" },
                new object[] { "Brand-" },
                new object[] { "Kassadin" },
                new object[] { "Kassadin" },
            };

            var list = values.SelectMany((row) => row).Select((item) => item.ToString());
            foreach (var item in list)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(item);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

with the expected output:

```
Kassadin
Wukong
Lucian-
Akali
Brand-
Kassadin
Kassadin
```